# How can I unset the content-type header with express

Tags: node.js, express, content-type

I am using express-js (4) as a test server, and it needs to behave similar to the real server.  The real server doesn't always send a content-type header, so I need to make the express server do the same thing.

```
  res.set('Content-Type', undefined);
  res.send('test get');
```

gives me 'invalid media type'

Is there any way to tell it not to send a `content-type` header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if anybody else is interested, to send with no `content-type` header, just use `res.end` instead of `res.send`

```
res.end('test get');
```